# Ethereum: How to create new account using web3.py?

Tags: python, web3.py

Using web3.py, I'm gonna create new account, however, I can't get passphrase.

> Generates a new account in the node’s keychain encrypted with the
>   given passphrase. Returns the address of the created account.
>
> web3.personal.newAccount('the-passphrase')
>   ['0xd3cda913deb6f67967b99d67acdfa1712c293601']

I saw this paragraph in Web3.py docs.
How to generate passphrase?

Comment: You can use any passphrase as you wish.It will generate address and the private key encrypted with the given passphrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'the-passphrase' is password to be supplied by you, which will be used to encrypt new account's private key.

So when you will access this new account, system will ask for password which was used to encrypt account's private key.

Comment: Hi @kherwa! I have an issue. Function `web3.personal.newAccount` is not active. Or do you have a method to create a new account?

Comment: How you have setup ethereum node and instantiated web3 object?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to ethereum. Now I am devoloping project that create account and is able to send and receive ethereum. Need I setup ethereum node? Without ethereum node, can not I develop project? Excuse me, can you tell me how to contact you? I need your help. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I sent email to you with my skype ID. There pls describe in details. Sorry.